# Spring data JPA waiting find

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have some method which import prices for airports and save it to database through Spring data JPA repositories.

Import method is this:

```
@Transactional
public Future<Boolean> importFuel(File serverFile, Long providerIdLong) {
    final FuelProvider fuelProvider = fuelProviderRepository
            .findOne(providerIdLong);
    LOG.debug("fuelProvider:" + fuelProvider.getName());
    List<AirportFuel> airportFuels = processors
            .get(providerIdLong).process(serverFile, fuelProvider);
    if(airportFuels==null){
        return new AsyncResult<>(false);
    }

    airportFuelRepository.deleteByFpId(providerIdLong);
    airportFuelRepository.save(airportFuels);
    fuelProvider.setUpdated(new Date());
    fuelProviderRepository.save(fuelProvider);
    return new AsyncResult<>(true);
}
```

For example this is read method:

```
List<AirportFuel> airportFuels = airportFuelRepository.findByIata(airport.getIata());
```

and AirportFuelRepository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AirportFuelRepository extends CrudRepository<AirportFuel, 
Long> {


   @Transactional
   @Modifying
   @Query("delete from AirportFuel af where af.fpId = :#{#fpId}")
   void deleteByFpId(@Param("fpId") Long fpId);

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   List<AirportFuel> findByIata(String iata);

   List<AirportFuel> findByIataAndFpId(String iata, Long fpId);

}
```

Application is based on Spring boot, Hibernate, Spring data JPA and MS SQL.

If import method running then other method which also use airportFuelRepository waiting for end of this method and i do not know why. I suppose the reading method will work with the data before the import and will not waiting to end import method.

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to have both methods be able to access the same repository asynchronously.

In order to do this annotate your method with the `@Async` annotation.

A few links to get you started:

- [baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)
- [Spring Quickstart](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)
- [Spring Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)
- [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-transaction)

Comment: Import method is called by JmsListener through MQ, it sould be async. But i tried your advice but without result. The read method is block if import method is on the end and commits data. I forgot to add that the number of entities with which it is handled in the order of thousands.